# HP Probook 470 - upgrade Win 8 -> Win 8.1 ends up with the black screen

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, graphics-card

I am trying to upgrade Windows 8 to Windows 8.1 on HP Probook 470. This notebook has both integrated Intel HD Graphics 4000 and more powerful AMD Radeon HD 8750M graphics cards, both working fine.

Unfortunately Microsoft released some update related to this AMD graphic card which actually breaks the working driver and after reboot I end up with black screen and mouse cursor only. Then I restart the computer and the system automatically uninstalls this optional update. This is fine.

But when I try to upgrade Windows 8 to 8.1 (first I install all mandatory updates and all optional updates except the broken one) using Windows Store, the whole installation process goes well and after the final reboot I end up with the black screen again. Obviously the broken update is installed during upgrade. When I reboot the computer, the system tries to restore the previous version of Windows - sometimes it succeeds, sometimes not.

I have backup image of Windows 8 installation, therefore I can try to make the upgrade more times. So far I have tried:

- Enable safe mode before upgrade. But I cannot enter it after the upgrade 
  fails.
- Install newest AMD driver. System refuses it because it wants driver
  customized by the manufacturer.
- Disable driver before upgrade. Does not help (system enables it automatically 
  again).
- Hide the broken update before upgrade. Does not help, system yet installs it.

Please does anybody have another suggestion on how to upgrade the system, eg. totally disable the broken update?